# Suggestions on making this bit of Javascript code better?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a way to add functions under a specific namespace (dpcom). This may be in dot notation depending on what the user did in their javascript file.  So basically, what I want them to do is something like this:

```
dpcom.library('something.foo.funcName', function() {
    // Code goes here.
})
```

They can then call their stuff later like:

```
dpcom.something.foo.funcName();
```

Which will execute the code they defined above.  The code I want help with in making it better is here (it's using jQuery):

```
dpcom.library = function(name, func) {
    root = dpcom;
    objects = name.split('.');
    lastElement = objects[objects.length - 1];

    $(objects).each(function(idx, elem) {
        if (elem == lastElement) {
            root[elem] = func;
        } else if (!root[elem]) {
            root[elem] = {}
        }
        root = root[elem];
    });
}
```

This should handle the possible dot notation and create objects inside of my namespace if they don't already exist (I don't want to overwrite any already declared objects).

The code I have above seems to work great, but I have a feeling I can make it better but my brain isn't telling me where...  Anyone want to take a stab at it?

Comment: If you think code can be sexy, you're beyond help IMO ;-)

Comment: I fully agree... I'm beyond help at this point.  :)

Comment: Why don't you just tattoo your code onto some pretty girl or guy, depending on your sexual orientation?

Seriously: why would anyone label a piece of code as "sexy"? A code can be efficient (not resource hungry), swift, easy to maintain, easy to extend, easy to read and understand, etc, but... "sexy"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a slightly more appealing manner using [*shift()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift):

```
dpcom.library = function(name, func) {
    var root = dpcom,
        objects = name.split('.'),
        elem;

    while (elem = objects.shift()) {
        if (objects.length) {
            if (!root[elem])
                root[elem] = {};
            root = root[elem];
        }
        else
            root[elem] = func;
    }
}
```

This way, you can ditch the jQuery requirement.  Also, don't forget to explicitly declare your vars with the *var* keyword.

Depending on your definition of sexy code, you could also replace this block:

```
        if (objects.length) {
            if (!root[elem])
                root[elem] = {};
            root = root[elem];
        }
```

with:

```
        if (objects.length) 
            root = !root[elem] ? root[elem] = {} : root[elem];
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this some kind of weird code-golf?

Try this, it might work...

```
dpcom.library = function(name, func) {
  var p = name.split('.'), e, root = this;
  while (e = p.shift()) root = root[e] = root[e] || (!p.length ? func : {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stab at it

```
dpcom.library = function(name, func) {
    var lastElement, root = dpcom, objects = name.split(/\./);
    lastElement = objects[objects.length - 1];

    $.each(objects, function(idx, elem) {
        if (!root[elem]) {
            if (elem == lastElement) {
                root[elem] = func;
            } else {
                root[elem] = {}
                root = root[elem];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've found myself using jQuery's extend method for this.  Check out the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

Answer (score 1):

Using the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method for Arrays,

```
dpcom.library = function(key, value) {
    var objects = key.split('.');
    var leaf = objects.pop();

    var constructHierarchy = function(object, property) {
        return (object[property] = object[property] || {});
    };

    objects.reduce(constructHierarchy, dpcom)[leaf] = value;
};
```

To increase the sexiness factor, make the second value generic and not just a function. It is already being done in all answers, but being explicit about it helps :)

```
dpcom.library('awesome.object', { foo: 'woah' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is any sexier or more readable, but it doesn't need *da Query* and hasn't any global vars ;)

```
var dpcom = {'test': null, 'something': {}};
dpcom.library = function(name, func) {
    for(var i = 0, node = this, names = name.split('.'), l = names.length; i < l; i++) {
        node = node[names[i]] = ((i == l - 1) ? func : node[names[i]] || {});
    }
};

dpcom.library('something.foo.funcName', function() {
    // Code goes here.
});
```

Result:

```
{ test: null
, library: [Function]
, something: { foo: { funcName: [Function] } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out YUI 2's namespace function:

```
YAHOO.namespace('myNS').funcName = function(){/* do something with arguments */};
```